# Can a table in different schema have totally different rows?

Tags: database, oracle, schema

Please help me to clarify with the following question about Oracle database:

Say a database has a table called Employee. Both SchemaA and SchemaB use employee table. SchemaA.Employee and SchemaB.Employee are totally different?

1. In terms of content (rows)
2. In terms of structures (Columns names and data types)

Please let me know.  I use Oracle a lot under fixed Schema.

If any of the above is true, then under the same database, we can have developer schema, test schema, production Schema and training schema. Is that true?

Comment: If any of the above is true, then under the same database, we can have developer schema, test schema, Production Schema and training schema.  Is that true?

Comment: True on all questions. Tables by the same name in different schemas are no different from tables with different names (in the same schema or in different schemas). If you know any kind of programming, think "scope" of a name. The scope of a table name is the schema it's in. This is why whenever you need to reference a table (or view or any kind of object) in another schema, you must precede the object name by the schema name.

Comment: Define 'use' in your second paragraph. They may be independent tables; or one schema may have access to an object in the other schema. What does the data dictionary show? And do you have public synonyms to allow cross-schema queries? You certainly can have separate schemas with objects with the same name, that are completely independent; and thus have dev/test in the same DB (but I wouldn't expect production in the same place). We can't tell you if you currently do, though.

Comment: Thanks mathguy and Alex.  I am not a DBA and I don't do DBA work.  I just use database with a fixed schema. and I am trying to understand some logic. This means different schema are like totally different database. What different schema share in common under the same database?  I am not an Oracle person. I believe this is totally not the case with MSSQL,

Comment: @SimonD - it depends. By default each schema is isolated, with only the data dictionary (`all_objects` etc.) and some SYS-owned things like directories in common, plus storage and processes. But you can share things across schemas, with privilege grants and sometimes views or synonyms to hide the details. I believe a schema is roughly equivalent to a 'database' in other DBMS, but it's not quite that simple. [This might help?](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/tablecls.htm#CNCPT111)